# How to access the ACS token on mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, acs

I am using Access Control Service (ACS). I configure my MVC-4 application to use ACS. I put the return url to my controller, which is `http://127.0.0.1:81/ACS/LogOn` and after logon with any identity provider we are successfully return to the controller. But now can anybody please tell me how i can access the issued token in the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've used the normal WIF-based mechanisms to configure your app to use ACS, everything you need should be accessible via Thread.CurrentPrincipal. In most cases, you don't want the token itself but instead you want the claims within it. See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061.aspx).

If you actually need the underlying token in XML/string form rather than the claims (I wouldn't recommend this most of the time) then you can get it by setting [SaveBoostrapContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.configuration.identityconfigurationelement.savebootstrapcontext.aspx) in your service configuration to true and accessing it via the [BootstrapContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.bootstrapcontext.aspx) property on the claims identity.

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.BootstrapContext;`

Comment: This blog post has a bit more info if you decide to go the bootstrap route:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2012/11/30/using-the-bootstrapcontext-property-in-net-4-5.aspx